# Looking for a short science fiction story about a giantess and a man sent to kill her

Tags: story-identification

I must have read this close to 10 years ago, I do remember it was in a collection of short stories, most likely an anthology of different authors.

I remember the man was with some organization that trained its agents to eliminate threats on different planets.  A call comes in about a giantess terrorizing villages on some world and the man is sent to kill her.  I recall something about the higher ups realizing they had sent the wrong man for this particular job, and were afraid he would be killed.

That's about all I can recall of it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated! This one's been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction July 1973] [image: Urania 637]

Possibly ["**The Giantess**"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50631) by Robert F Young.

The story has appeared in couple of publications, including  "The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction: July 1973" and "Urania #637" (pictured above). The following are some excerpts:

> Hill saw no sign of his quarry. Nevertheless, he knew she was
> somewhere in the valley. The Hujiri had told him she was childlike in
> more ways than one and kept irregular hours. More than likely she was
> taking a nap in some secluded bower.

This passage soon after he spots his target:

> Consequently, it was some time before he realized that the young and
> lovely girl sleeping at the foot of the cliff far exceeded her seeming
> size.

And this segment reflects the doubts his higher-ups had:

> It had occurred to Galactic Guidance. Hill's dossier contained not only
> the information he had volunteered but the data GG's investigative
> division had dug up behind his back. The latter far outweighed the
> former, and it said as plain as day that a mission involving a
> sadistic giantess would be suicidal for Norman Hill. Why, then, had
> Galactic Guidance dispatched him post-haste to Primeval?

You can read the complete story [here](http://giantessworld.net/Stories6/giantess__by_robert_f.htm) or [here](http://www.doc88.com/p-18264349202.html).

Comment: Oh goodness... that is really a story now, isn't it.

Comment: I could have sworn I commented on your answer when I accepted it. Hmm. But thank you (again!) for your very informative answer and the links to the story itself. Much appreciated!